# getAffineTransform fails when one of its argument matrices is not continuous?

Tags: opencv

I'm using openCv 2.4.6.

The following doesn't work:

```
  cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1], 1);

  int x11 = src.rows/3; int y11 = src.cols/3;
  int x12 = src.rows/3; int y12 = src.rows*2/3;
  int x13 = src.cols*2/3; int y13 = src.rows*2/3;

  int x21 = 0; int y21 = 0;
  int x22 = 0; int y22 = src.rows-1;
  int x23 = src.cols-1; int y23 = src.rows-1;

#if 1 // doesn't work
  float src_tri_data[] = {x11, y11, 0, x12, y12, 0, x13, y13, 0};
  cv::Mat src_tri(3, 2, CV_32F, src_tri_data, 3*sizeof(float));

  float dst_tri_data[] = {x21, y21, 0, x22, y22, 0, x23, y23, 0};
  cv::Mat dst_tri(3, 2, CV_32F, dst_tri_data, 3*sizeof(float));
#else // works
  float src_tri_data[] = {x11, y11, x12, y12, x13, y13};
  cv::Mat src_tri(3, 2, CV_32F, src_tri_data, 2*sizeof(float));

  float dst_tri_data[] = {x21, y21, x22, y22, x23, y23};
  cv::Mat dst_tri(3, 2, CV_32F, dst_tri_data, 2*sizeof(float));
#endif

  cv::Mat trans = cv::getAffineTransform(src_tri, dst_tri);
```

It fails with an assertion:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 3 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 3) in unknown function, file C:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 3612

However, if I make the matrices continuous it works.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The assertions check that the size of the row of index 2 contains 3 elements but your matrices contains 2 elements per row.
The size of the matrices are not correct, modify the construction of your matrices :

```
cv::Mat src_tri(3,
                3,               // <=== 3 instead of 2
                CV_32F,
                src_tri_data,
                3*sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Well, I do want a 3x2 matrix with a stride (or 'step' as it's called in openCv terminology), so changing the number of columns from 2 to 3 does not seem to be the right thing to do.